# Control position of select options in Chrome OSX

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome

I have a custom styled select in a `span`. I'm happy with how it looks.

```css
span.select {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
}
span.select select {
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  display: block;
  background: transparent;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 55px 0 15px;
  background: orange;
}
span.select:after {
  content: "";
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: blue;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding: 30px">
  <span class="select">
    <select name="" id="">
      <option value="">An option within a select</option>
    </select>
  </span>
  
</div>

<div style="padding: 30px">
  <span class="select">
    <select name="" id="">
      <option value="">An option within a select</option>
    </select>
  </span>
  
</div>
```

The issue I have, is that when it is clicked, the options are appearing a few pixels to the left and maybe 1px lower than I would like. The options should really appear exactly inside the border of the span.

I know the clickable options themselves are a UI element and not styleable, however is there a reset or a hack I can apply to make them appear in the center, without destroying the experience in other browsers?

[image: Select unclicked and clicked]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are needing this to work only for OSX or for other operating systems but on windows it looks completely different then your screenshot. If you are using the build in select element to visualize the options, you will not have great control over them. The reason is that the dropdown lives outside the HTML and CSS control (it is OS overlay ontop of the browser). I will suggest to you to make every visible part of your dropdown custom, in this way you will have full control over it. You can still use the "select" tag for all the built-in events and ease of use, just hide it completely.

And if you need to just make it work with this approach only on OSX, in your place, i would try move the perceived position of the select a bit to the left and down. I say perceived instead of the actual, because if you actually move it, the options will move as well. So make some div or something like that to be position behind the select, and make it look like the select starts more to the left and lower.
Hope this hack works.

```css
span{
    background-color: orange;
}
.dropdownSelectedOption{
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
span.select {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
}
span.select select {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
    border: none;
    display: block;
    background: transparent;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    background: transparent;
}
span.select:after {
    content: "";
    width: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: blue;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="select">
    <div class="dropdownSelectedOption">An option within a select</div>
    <select name="" id="" onchange="updateUI(event)">
        <option value="An option within a select">An option within a select</option>
        <option value="option 2 within a select">option 2 within a select</option>
    </select>
</span>

<script>
    function updateUI(event){
        event.target.parentElement.querySelector('.dropdownSelectedOption').innerText = event.target.value;
    }
</script>
```

By changing the top and left position of the select, you will move where the options will appear. (i have put the 10px for each for the example)